# Is it possible to lock a DLL in C so that others can't use it?

Tags: c#, c, dll, loadlibrary

I am using a program that contains an EXE file and some DLLs written in C language. I want to rewrite this program in C#. For this purpose, I need to use DLLs.

The problem is that I have trouble loading one of the DLLs, but the rest of the DLLs are loaded without any problem. Is it possible that this DLL is locked? In addition, with C language, I also tried to load DLL using the load library as in the example below, but the hDLL variable returns a null value.

```c
    HINSTANCE hDLL = NULL;
    
    hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\projects\\sam_cards\\mydll.dll");
```

And I used the following code for C#

```cs
    [DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int VerifyAddPin(int comid, IntPtr pin);
    
    IntPtr s = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Hello");
    
    int a = VerifyAddPin(2, s);
```

Comment: What is a Dell?

Comment: Examine the return value of [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) and tell us

Comment: The title and body of your question ask two different things, plus, what's "Dell"? Do you mean the Dell company? Also, what's the error code returned by [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)?

Comment: Hi  Jabberwocky
No, I mean the DLL file in general.
When I use loadlibrary, I don't get any specific error, only the output value is null, which indicates that the dll is not loaded. But I don't have this problem for other DLLs.

Comment: 32bit vs 64bit?

Comment: I tried both...

Comment: @MohamadElyasi Once LoadLibrary returns NULL, print the value of `GetLastError` ad already suggested twice in previous comments. The error number will give us a clue and then we can help.

Comment: The error number is 193

Comment: @MohamadElyasi 193 basically means that your dll is corrupted. Are you sure the file is _actually_ a dll? Or maybe your process is a 32 bit process and the dll is a 64 bit dll or the other way round

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use WIN 32 console Application in VS2015. I tried x86 and X64 in Configuration Manager.
This DLL is being used by another program, but I don't have the source code of that program

Comment: Is this DLL available for the public? If so, please [edit] your question and provide a link. -- You can try to use ProcessExplorer (originally by SysInternals, now Microsoft) to look at this other program and see if/how it uses that DLL and some details about it. Perhaps it is some kind of anti-abuse measure, and the file is just named "mydll.dll" but is no DLL. -- Did you try any other tool to check that DLL? Please don't add such important information in a comment, [edit] your question.

Comment: @thebusybee  No, the DLL is not public. Yes, I'm sure another program uses this DLL and its functions. I also have the .h file related to this DLL.
I have changed the important information about the codes. Thank you for your notice.
But my main question is, is there a way to lock a C DLL so it won't load in other apps?

Comment: I never heard of such an option, and it contradicts one of the main purposes of DLLs. As the error code tells you, most probably this is no valid DLL. That's why I gave you the hint to use a checker tool.